# scrape all tables off web page with beautiful soup and condense into one csv file

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The page that I am scraping has many small tables on it, the code that I have runs through and makes a csv file for each table. I want to condense all tables into one csv file. any one know how to do this? Below is my code that will spit out a csv file for each table. Do I need to scrape my data differently?

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
from requests import get
import pandas as pd
from csv import writer
url = 'https://www.vegasinsider.com/college-basketball/scoreboard/scores.cfm/game_date/01-12-2020'
source = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
tables = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class':'sportPicksBorder'})
for num, table in enumerate(tables, start=1):
    filename = 'C:\\Users\\MyName\\Documents/table-%d.csv' % num
    with open(filename, 'w')as f:
        data = []
        csv_writer = writer(f)
        rows = table.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            headers = row.find_all('th')
            if headers:
                csv_writer.writerow([header.text.strip()for header in headers])
            columns = row.find_all('td')
            csv_writer.writerow([column.text.strip() for column in columns])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve it by moving the 'writer' outside of the for loop:

```py
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
from requests import get
import pandas as pd
from csv import writer
url = 'https://www.vegasinsider.com/college-basketball/scoreboard/scores.cfm/game_date/01-12-2020'
source = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
tables = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class': 'sportPicksBorder'})
filename = 'C:\\Users\\MyName\\Documents\\tables.csv'
with open(filename, 'w')as f:
    data = []
    csv_writer = writer(f)
    for table in tables:
        rows = table.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            columns = row.find_all('td')
            csv_writer.writerow([column.text.strip() for column in columns])
```

This writes everything in a single csv file, but the data is a bit messy and will still require cleanup. I can't figure out how your original code would have cleaned it any more though, when I load that webpage there are no th tags, everything is a tr/td. Additionally I did this on a Mac so I'm not sure if that file path for tables.csv is formatted properly.

Comment: Your additions worked well to get it into one CSV file. Yes, I know there are no headers on this site, another that site I have tried this on had headers. The file path outputs a file the documents folder on my windows laptop the path may be a little different on a mac. My next step is figuring out how to clean up the table, but I am not sure how to loop through multiple 'td' classes to find only the data that I need.